# Ansible-lint Throwing error "ERROR! 'raw' is not a valid attribute for a Play"

Tags: ansible

I have yaml file with just couple of tasks that i'm including in another Yaml file.

The play book is running fine, but when i run ansible-lint against the yaml file with tasks, it's throwing the error

> ERROR! 'raw' is not a valid attribute for a Play.

```
- name: Clusters Info
  raw: "show-clusters-info cluster-id={{item}}"
  register: Clusters_Info
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Show XMS Info
  raw: "show-xms"
  register: show_xms_info
  ignore_errors: true
```

Answer (score 1):

A playbook is a list of **plays**. Your above example is only a list of **tasks** (which is I guess included in your playbook later on).

From the `ansible-lint` [README](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint)

> Usage: ansible-lint [options] [playbook.yml [playbook2 ...]]|roledirectory

So if you pass a file name directly to `ansible-lint`, it will try to analyze it as a playbook. The error you get is therefore expected. Either pass a playbook (which includes your task file) or a role directory (defaulting to current dir if empty) to analyze a playbook or a role.